# Node.js do action when object date match/ends

Tags: sql, node.js, time, monitoring, live

I am doing site with auctions, which has end_date parameter, and I want to finish that auction when the current date match end_date. So I wonder what is the best solution that I can use for it? I know that I can use "setInterval" to check the database every second, but is this the best solution? Maybe is there a better idea, which monitors dates without checking SQL in intervals?
I also cannot start the process with static dates (end_dates), because if the user makes an offer end_date is changing, so the node has to monitor it "live".

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so:

##### Server

- When the server starts, it loads the `end_date` once. If the auction is already finished (and stored as such in db) then do nothing. If it is still running, you probably want to set a `setTimeout` which will set a flag like `ended` to in the database for a given auction, at the moment it is finished.
- Whenever something on the auction is changed in database from any source, you will have to clear an existing timeout and reset it with the new value.

#### Client

- The client would always receive the `end_date` value and show either `auction finished` or `still running` etc.. So the client correctly can end the auction in the browser if any user would have the tab open. This is backed by some `setInterval` OR `setTimeout` calls for correctly showing a countdown, or updating the auctions state or preventing the user from doing stuff etc.

#### API

- Foreach request on a given auction you need to check against the flag set in database. Only allow a certain action for an auction if it is NOT already finished.

#### Pseudocode on server startup

```
// this assumes, that auction.end_date is a javascript date object.
// you may wanna adjust this to your envrionment. 
function setAuctionEndedTrigger(auction) {
    // calculates remaining milliseconds till auction will end.
    const remaining_time = auction.end_date.getTime() - Date.now()

    setTimeout(() => {
        // store in the database that the auction has ended!
        // 1 for true and 0 for false.
        sql.execute(`update auctions set ended=1 where id = '${auction.id}'; `)
       

    }, remaining_time)
}


// Code ecexuted when server starts
// Pseudocode... 

// load auctions from db which have not already ended:
const auctions = await sql.execute('select * from auctions where ended is null OR ended = 0;')

// for each running auction set a trigger! 
for(let auction of auctions) {
    setAuctionEndedTrigger(auction)
}
```